# High latency from Google CDN - how to troubleshoot it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn

We are trying to find out why there is a high latency from Google CDN.

Our site is behind Google'a http_load_balancer with CDN turned on.

For example, by inspecting sampe GET request for a jpg file (43Kb), we can see from http_load_balancer logs that around 30% of such requests have `httpRequest.latency` > 1 second, and a lot are taking much longer like several or hundreds of seconds....

This is just by looking at 24h log sample (around 6K the same requests).

The `httpRequest.cacheLookup` and `httpRequest.cacheHit` for all of those requests are `true`.
Also `jsonpayload_type_loadbalancerlogentry.statusdetails` is `response_from_cache` and `jsonpayload_type_loadbalancerlogentry.cacheid` values shows correct region.

When doing the same GET request manually in the browser we are getting expected results with TTFB around 15-20ms.

Any idea where to look for a clue?

Comment: Check this [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/troubleshooting-steps) guide.

Comment: Thanks just had a look but I did not find anything around latency.

Comment: In order to optimizing application latency with LB, you can follow this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tutorials/optimize-app-latency#optimizing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `httpRequest.latency` field measures the entire download duration, and is directly impacted by slow clients - e.g. a mobile device on a congested network or throttled data plan.

You can check this by looking at the `frontend_tcp_rtt` metric (which is the RTT between the client and Cloud CDN) in Cloud Monitoring, as well as the average, median and 90th percentile `total_latencies`, where the slow clients will show up as outliers: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#monitoring_metrics_fors

You may find that slow clients are from a specific group of `client_country` values.

Comment: thanks for this info. I had a look here [httpRequest.latency](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#httprequest) and not sure `httpRequest.latency` measures the entire download duration. Is that field calculated based on final response from the client? Is there any metrics that shows how my site is performing at LoadBalancer (`http_load_balancer`) level in terms of response time?

Comment: The metrics will give you performance from client <-> LB - e.g. round-trip-time (RTT) on the TCP connection, rather than the final response duration. This is also much easier to look at in aggregate vs. log data - https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-loadbalancing

Answer (score 0):

Latency can be introduced:

- **Between the original client and the load balancer**.
  You can see the latency of that segment with the metric `https/frontend_tcp_rtt`.
- **Between the load balancer and the backend instance**.
  Which can be reviewed with the metric `https/backend_latencies` (this metric also includes the app processing time in your backend).
- **By the software running on the instance itself**.
  To investigate this I would check the access/error logs on the backend instance software and resource utilization of the VM instance.

Further information about metrics description on the [GCP load balancer metrics doc](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-loadbalancing).

`httpRequest.latency` log field [description](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#httprequest):
"The request processing latency on the server, from the time the request was received until the response was sent."